# Cloning questions for different versions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Does it make sense to clone a question for a different version of a game?  For example I saw [What happens to the bonuses when I build a city in a special resource tile?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8688/what-happens-to-the-bonuses-when-i-build-a-city-in-a-special-resource-tile) and immediately wanted to know the answer to that with regards to Civ 4, so I asked [What happens to a resource when I build a city on its tile?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/what-happens-to-a-resource-when-i-build-a-city-on-its-tile).

Is there anything wrong with doing this?  It feels like cheating.

Comment: These are not different "versions", these are different games... and while certainly similar, many things do behave differently.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the problem in this case. Civ 4 and Civ 5 are distinct games with their own distinct rules and mechanics.

Comment: Just don't get seedin'...

Comment: @badp I'm with you on that.  If I hadn't planted a city on top of a sheep 30 mins before I asked, I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to first place a comment on the Civ 5 answer to ask if anyone knows if the same thing goes for Civ 4. If it doesn't or nobody answers, feel free to open a new question, since as @LessPop_Morefizz points out they are two very different games.

Comment: The advantage of this in a general sense is that it might turn out that one answer applies to multiple versions - the question could then be modified accordingly.